# How to add ANOVA one-way p-value to ggplot with ggsignif

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have the following data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)
set.seed(1)
a <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 5, sd = 1)
b <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 5.8, sd = 1)

data <- data.frame(label = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)), id = c(1:10, 1:10), 
                   value = c(a, b))
```

And I perform the one-way anova pot using this code:

```
aa <- aov( value ~ label, data)
summary(aa)
```

Which produces:

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
label        1  4.201   4.201   4.793  0.042 *
Residuals   18 15.779   0.877                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Notice the p-value is 0.042.

However when I tried with [ggsignif](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/vignettes/intro.html) with this code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = label, y = value )) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_signif(comparison = list(c("A",  "B")), y_position = 11, test = function(a, b) {
    list(p.value = summary(aov(a ~ b))[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][[1]])
  })
```

I got this:

[image]

Note the p-value stated there is 0.28 instead of 0.042.
What's the right way to do it, so that I can put the 0.042 value inside the plot?

Answer (score 3):

The p-value of one-way anova with two group is the same as t.test.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = label, y = value )) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_signif(comparison = list(c("A",  "B")), y_position = 11, test = "t.test")
```

Answer (score 2):

@cuttlefish44 is right. For two groups comparisons, t-test is more appropriate.

Just to mention this alternative to `geom_signif`, you can also get the p-value on the plot using `stat_compare_means` from the `ggpubr` package:

```r
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = label, y = value )) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = 7)+
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("A","B")), method = "t.test", label.y = 8)
```

[image]